# set different input value when clicking on buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 buttons and an input, i want when i click on one of those buttons the value or source of this input to change according to the button, like for example when i click on the first button it passes apple, when i click on button two it passes orange, etc.. 
How can i do that? here is what i have tried so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click( function() {
        $('input').val('value');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Button 1</button>
<button type="button">Button 2</button>
<button type="button">Button 3</button>

<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Add custom attribute button element and pass it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could even use `id`s on the buttons. However, in this example I think it's more semantic using a `data-attribute` on each button like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('input').val($(this).data('attribute'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-attribute='apple'>Button 1</button>
<button type="button" data-attribute='orange'>Button 2</button>
<button type="button" data-attribute='banana'>Button 3</button>

<input type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add custom attribute button element ans pass it your click event
HTML:

```
<button type="button" data-fruit="apple">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" data-fruit="banana">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" data-fruit="orange">Button 3</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click( function() {
    var fruit = $(this).attr('data-fruit');
    $('input').val(fruit);
  });
});
```

Comment: Just FYI you should use `data()` when getting `data` attributes as it's quicker and saves DOM accesses.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this even with simple javascript....

```js
function insertValue(btn) {
  document.getElementById("input").value = btn;
}
```

```html
<button   onClick='insertValue("Orange")'>Orange</button>
<button  onClick='insertValue("banana")'>banana</button>
<button  onClick='insertValue("Apple")'>Apple</button>

<input type=text id="input" />
```